# Date Time Conversion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, sql-update

I imported a CSV file into MySQL. The CSV file contains Date/Time in the format `'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm'`.

It gets imported into MySQL only as text. So I did import it as text. I then created another field hoping to convert this text value to date time in this format `'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm'` OR in this format `'YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm'`. But it does not work. Below is my code.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN StartDateNEW DATETIME;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE table1 SET StartDateNEW = STR_TO_DATE(StartDate, '%m/%e/Y %H:%i');
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

Sample Data:

[image]

Some more sample data:

[image]

I have been trying this for over an hour now. Can someone please help?

Comment: You probably want `'%m/%d/Y %H:%i'` (`%d`, not `%e`)

Comment: It does not work with %d either. I used %e because %e
Day of the month as a numeric value (0 to 31) and %d
Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31). Either way, it doesn't work. I tried both.

Comment: Are you loading the data using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax?

Comment: No. This is the error I am getting even with %c/%e/%Y %k:%I.

Comment: Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '3/31/2012 23:54' for function str_to_date 0.000 sec

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading data using [the `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), it should be possible to handle conversion on the fly.

Assuming that your source csv file looks like:

```
StartDate, EndDate, Value
"1/10/2012 10:05", "1/11/2012 11:51", abc
"1/13/2012 08:00", "1/15/2012 09:01", abc
```

You can defined columns `StartDate` and  `EndDate` as `datetime` datatype, and simply do:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/my/file.csv' INTO TABLE mytable
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' -- or '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@StartDate, @EndDate, Value)
    SET 
        StartDate = STR_TO_DATE(@StartDate, '%c/%e/%Y %k:%i'),
        EndDate =   STR_TO_DATE(@EndDate,   '%c/%e/%Y %k:%i')
;
```

NB: and if you are curently not using `LOAD DATA INFILE`... I would still recommend migrating your code to use it. This is the proper way to do this in MySQL, it works on all clients.... and it is very fast (see [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html)).

Comment: I am using the Table Import Wizard in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @stat77: I would recommend using `LOAD DATA INFILE` anway. This is the proper way to do this in MySQL, and it works on all clients.

Comment: I have an Excel CSV file. What part of your code should I modify to fit that?

Comment: @stat77: check out the example I gave in my answer. And there are many resources available on SO or elsewhere on the web that document or show examples of how this nice MySQL feature works.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, the correct format string for `STR_TO_DATE` is

```
%c/%e/%Y %k:%i
```

- `%c` allows for single digit month numbers
- `%e` allows for single digit day numbers
- `%Y` four digit year
- `%k` allows for single digit hours
- `%i` two digit minutes

All the format strings are described in the manual for [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=25382975932979a122ec38c092f746df)

Comment: Getting an error even with %c/%e/%Y. Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '3/31/2012 23:54' for function str_to_date 0.000 sec

Comment: @stat77 that is a value I have working in my demo... are there extra spaces around the data?

Comment: It is strange. 3/31/2012  11:54:00 PM. I use the LEN function in Excel LEN(3/31/2012  11:54:00 PM) and it gives me 16. There are certainly more than 16 characters.

Comment: @stat77 and `LEN('3/31/2012 23:54')` should give 15 which is also not 16...

Comment: There are two spaces between the date and time.

Comment: @stat77 then you just need to add the second space to the format string i.e. `%c/%e/%Y  %k:%i` as `STR_TO_DATE` needs the string to match **exactly**

Comment: Can you copy and paste the **exact** string into a comment?

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack is as follows:

1. Open CSV File in Excel
2. Select the date column
3. Change date format to `yyyy-mm-dd` using cell format popup
4. Save file
5. Import to MySQL

This was you don't need to import in text form and then try to convert the data into `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks but I want to retain the time. Otherwise, I would have done exactly that.

Comment: I think Time will not be lost

Comment: You are right. Time is not displayed in the cell but is not lost.